# Unexpected low values in LOESS regression

Tags: r, regression, loess

The following plot is generated using the `scatterplot` function from `R`'s `car` package.

The red "nonparametric-regression smooth" generated by `loessLine` drops way below any values in the data set around 2270 and on the end. What am I to make of this?

[image: Scatterplot with unexpected low loess regression values]

R code generating the plot:

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="X     Y
2040    5.5
2186    4.5
2232    4.6
2238    4.6
2238    4.6
2262    4.3
2272    4
2272    4.4
2272    4.4
2281    4.8
2281    5
2289    4.4
2295    3.6
2318    4.3
2353    4.5")

require('car')

scatterplot(Y~X,data=df,ylim=c(0,8))
```

Comment: The Loess line is the green line, not either red one.  The documentation indicates the red curves are the "smoothed conditional spread."  They are produced (by default) by `car::loessLine`: look at its code to see how it does it.  (It is based on separate Loess fits of the positive and negative residuals of the original Loess fit.)  See http://www.netlib.org/a/dloess for documentation.

Comment: Sorry for mixing up the terminology. Yet the green line is created by `reg` parameter with the default `lm`. So I don't think I should call that the Loess line either. Thanks for the link but I don't think that counts as documentation.

Comment: Pardon me?  The link (a) contains the original source code and (b) provides access to documentation by the original authors, a "50 page user guide."  They write "This guide describes crucial steps in the proper analysis of data using `-loess`.  **Please read it.**"

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that as you might excuse due to the extensive formatting of that documentation. Sadly I also couldn't find that user guide on that FTP.